# Preg_match doesn't work when pattern and subject inside preg_quote - PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-quote

I am trying to preg_match by using preg_quote for my pattern and subject.
Problem is that preg_match doesn't seem to match them.

I removed the preg_quote and it matched me just fine.
I preg_quote subject and message to see what it's the output and they are exactly the same but preg_match doesn't seem to match them.
I need to have the preg_quote for some cases.

```
$message = "My two great things in life are spaghetti and bolognese Order yours #online from Ammou Pizza in Limassol!

foody.com.cy/ammou-pizza";

if(preg_match('#' . preg_quote("ammou-pizza") . '#',  preg_quote($message)))
    echo 'here';
```

I expect the output to be 'here' but the actual output is just the exit code 0.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference in your sample but just to mention, it's important to also specify the delimiter when using preg_quote: `'#'.preg_quote("blafoo","#").'#'`... else the regex will break as soon as you have an `#` in your search substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `preg_quote($message)` for your original text in the subject to search .  This is ONLY to make sure any text is a valid regex expression.  If you echo out the result of this you get...

```
My two great things in life are spaghetti and bolognese Order yours #online from Ammou Pizza in Limassol\!

foody\.com\.cy/ammou\-pizza
```

and as you can see it has encoded `ammou\-pizza`.  This isn't what you want, the `\-` sequence is only needed as `-` is means something different to regex other than a simple dash.

Just use...

```
if(preg_match('#' . preg_quote("ammou-pizza") . '#',  $message))
```

Answer (score 1):

`preg_quote` is useless here because you have no special character in your regex, use:

```
if ( preg_match('#ammou-pizza#', $message) )
    echo 'here';
```

In your case, the use of `preg_match` is not mandatory, uou'd better use `[strstr][1]`, it is much more efficient as you want to find a simple string:

```
if (strstr('ammou-pizza', $message) )
    echo 'here';
```

Comment: @NigelRen: You're probably right, but I've answered for this specific question. Let's OP decide what they really want. I agree that your answer is much more generic.

Comment: @NigelRen indeed answered my question.